# Maximise the AND

Tags: c++, algorithm

Given an array of n non-negative integers: A1, A2, …, AN. How to find a pair of integers Au, Av (1 ≤ u < v ≤ N) such that (Au and Av) is as large as possible.

Example : Let N=4 and array be [2 4 8 10] .Here answer is 8

Explanation

```
2 and 4 = 0
2 and 8 = 0
2 and 10 = 2
4 and 8 = 0
4 and 10 = 0
8 and 10 = 8
```

How to do it if N can go upto 10^5.
I have O(N^2) solution.But its not efficient

Code :

```
for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
    for(int j=i+1;j<n;j++){
        if(arr[i] & arr[j] > ans)
        {
            ans=arr[i] & arr[j];
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: "*Your mission is...*" - No, it's **YOUR** mission.

Comment: Probably a problem of any ongoing programming contest!

Comment: Sounds a lot like you're doing a Codility test.

Comment: Why not simply sort the array and then pick the last and second-last elements?  Unless they are the same, in which case continue going forward until finding the next one which is different.

Comment: @Jim Lewis @wallyk Well, it was my mistake. But consider this array `[3, 4, 6, 7, 8, 9, 17]`. This yields 8(8 & 9)

Comment: @wallyk How are you sure it will provide right ans ?

Comment: @user3878046:  It is obvious to me that it will provide the right answer because it exactly matches the problem posed.  Do you understand the problem?

Comment: @wallyk Wrong. For `[2 3 8 16 32 64]` the matching numbers are 2 & 3

Comment: @icepack:  According to the specification, the matching numbers are 32 and 64.

Comment: @wallyk You have to AND (not OR) the numbers. 32 & 64 = 0.

Comment: @KaidulIslamSazal Looks like somebody else is entering the same contest. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24978796/fastest-and-most-efficient-way-to-find-the-maximum-no-that-can-be-obtained-by-p

Comment: @user1990169:  Ah, I parsed the problem wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Sort the array in descending order.
2. Take the first two numbers. If they are both between two consecutive powers of 2 (say 2^k and 2^(k+1), then you can remove all elements that are less than 2^k.
3. From the remaining elements, subtract 2^k.
4. Repeat steps 2 and 3 until the number of elements in the array is 2.

Note: If you find that only the largest element is between 2^k and 2^(k+1) and the second largest element is less than 2^k, then you will not remove any element, but just subtract 2^k from the largest element.

Also, determining where an element lies in the series {1, 2, 4, 8, 16, ...} can be done in O(log(log(MAX))) time where MAX is the largest number in the array.

Comment: +1 except for this tiny flaw: if you subtract `2^k` from the first element only, you need to reinsert that element in the correct spot of your sorted array or you'll end up with wrong answers. Depending on your array implementation (cost of insertion) this can ruin the `O(n log n)` running time.

Comment: Yes we will have to insert this element in O (n) time. Still IMO the complexity of this algorithm is O (nlogn) because we only have atmost log (MAX) iterations. Each time we discard the most significant bit from the largest elements.

Comment: Absolutely true. Considering a default implementation you could even consider that a constant because integers are bounded in size.

Comment: Weird, why is this O(nlogn) solution being glorified over my O(n) solution?

Comment: @user1990169 I also upvoted your answer now but the reason I didn't yesterday is that I just didn't read it at all. I tend to skip 'code only' answers because I think an answer like this is just much easier too read. No offense, just explaining why a less optimal answer may float to the top.

Answer (score 5):

One way you could speed it up is to take advantage of the fact that if any of the high bits  are set in any two numbers, then the AND of those two number will ALWAYS be larger than any combination using lower bits.

Therefore, if you order your numbers by the bits set you may decrease the number of operations drastically.

In order to find the most significant bit efficiently, GCC has a builtin intrinsic: `__builtin_clz(unsigned int x)` that returns the index of the most significant set bit. (Other compilers have similar intrinsics, translating to a single instruction on at least x86).

```
const unsigned int BITS = sizeof(unsigned int)*8; // Assuming 8 bit bytes.

// Your implementation over.
unsigned int max_and_trivial( const std::vector<unsigned int> & input);    

// Partition the set.
unsigned int max_and( const std::vector<unsigned int> & input ) {
    // For small input, just use the trivial algorithm.
    if ( input.size() < 100 ) { 
        return max_and_trivial(input);
    }        

    std::vector<unsigned int> by_bit[BITS];

    for ( auto elem : input ) {
         unsigned int mask = elem;
         while (mask) { // Ignore elements that are 0.
             unsigned int most_sig = __builtin_clz(mask);
             by_bits[ most_sig ].push_back(elem);
             mask ^= (0x1 << BITS-1) >>  most_sig;
         }
    }

    // Now, if any of the vectors in by_bits have more 
    // than one element, the one with the highest index 
    // will include the largest AND-value.

    for ( unsigned int i = BITS-1; i >= 0; i--) {
        if ( by_bits[i].size() > 1 ) {
             return max_and_trivial( by_bits[i]);
        }
    }

    // If you get here, the largest value is 0.
    return 0;
}
```

This algorithm still has worst case runtime O(N*N), but on average it should perform much better. You can also further increase the performance by repeating the partition step when you search through the smaller vector (just remember to ignore the most significant bit in the partition step, doing this should increase the performance to a worst case of O(N)).

Guaranteeing that there are no duplicates in the input-data will further increase the performance.

Comment: Best answer I've seen to this thus far is Vlad's answer in this Q: https://stackoverflow.com/a/28324954/2430032

Answer (score 3):

I didn't test this, and I'm not going to. O(N) memory and O(N) complexity.

```
#include <vector>
#include <utility>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;


/*
 * The idea is as follows:
 * 1.) Create a mathematical set A that holds integers.
 * 2.) Initialize importantBit = highest bit in any integer in v
 * 3.) Put into A all integers that have importantBit set to 1.
 * 4.) If |A| = 2, that is our answer. If |A| < 2, --importantBit and try again. If |A| > 2, basically
 *     redo the problem but only on the integers in set A.
 *
 * Keep "set A" at the beginning of v.
 */
pair<unsigned, unsigned> find_and_sum_pair(vector<unsigned> v)
{
    // Find highest bit in v.
    int importantBit = 0;
    for(auto num : v)
        importantBit = max(importantBit, highest_bit_index(num));

    // Move all elements with imortantBit to front of vector until doing so gives us at least 2 in the set.
    int setEnd;
    while((setEnd = partial_sort_for_bit(v, importantBit, v.size())) < 2 && importantBit > 0)
        --importantBit;

    // If the set is never sufficient, no answer exists
    if(importantBit == 0)
        return pair<unsigned, unsigned>();

    // Repeat the problem only on the subset defined by A until |A| = 2 and impBit > 0 or impBit  = 0
    while(importantBit > 1)
    {
        unsigned secondSetEnd = partial_sort_for_bit(v, --importantBit, setEnd);
        if(secondSetEnd >= 2)
            setEnd = secondSetEnd;
    }

    return pair<unsigned, unsigned>(v[0], v[1]);
}

// Returns end index (1 past last) of set A
int partial_sort_for_bit(vector<unsigned> &v, unsigned importantBit, unsigned vSize)
{
    unsigned setEnd = 0;
    
    unsigned mask = 1<<(importantBit-1);
    for(decltype(v.size()) index = 0; index < vSize; ++index)
        if(v[index]&mask > 0)
            swap(v[index], v[setEnd++]);
    
    return setEnd;
}


unsigned highest_bit_index(unsigned i)
{
    unsigned ret = i != 0;
    while(i >>= 1)
        ++ret;
    return ret;
}
```

I came upon this problem again and solved it a different way (much more understandable to me):

```
unsigned findMaxAnd(vector<unsigned> &input) {
    vector<unsigned> candidates;
    for(unsigned mask = 1<<31; mask; mask >>= 1) {
        for(unsigned i : input)
            if(i&mask)
                candidates.push_back(i);
        if (candidates.size() >= 2)
            input = move(candidates);
        candidates = vector<unsigned>();
    }
    
    if(input.size() < 2) {
        return 0;

    return input[0]&input[1]; 
}
```

Comment: +1. But it's easier with `std::partition`; it even fits into a comment: `unsigned maxand(std::vector<unsigned> v) { auto begin = v.begin(), end = v.end(); for (unsigned bit = 1U<<32; bit; bit >>= 1) { auto part = std::partition(begin, end, [&](unsigned a)->bool{return a & bit;}); if (part > begin + 1) end = part; } return *begin & *(begin + 1); }`

Comment: Are you sure this is O (n)?

Comment: @user1990169: It does a partition of maximum size n using a maximum of n/2 swaps (which is thus O(n)) once for every bit in the representation of the elements of the values. Since the values aren't bignums, the RAM model says that we can take the bitlength as a constant. And O(cN) is in O(N) so the algorithm as presented is O(n).

Answer (score 0):

Here is an O(N * log MAX_A) solution:

1)Let's construct the answer greedily, iterating from the highest bit to the lowest one.

2)To do it, one can mantain a set S of numbers that currently fit. Initially, it consists of all numbers in the array. Let's also assume that initially ANS = 0.

3)Now lets iterate over all the bits from the highest to the lowest. Let's say that current bit is B.

4)If the number of elements in S with value 1 of the B-th bit is greater than 1, it is possible to have 1 in this position without changing the values of higher bits in ANS so we should add 2^B to the ANS and remove all elements from S which have 0 value of this bit(they do not fit anymore).

5)Otherwise, it is not possible to obtain 1 in this position, so we do not change S and ANS and proceed to the next bit.