# Fastest and most efficient way to find the maximum no. that can be obtained by performing bitwise and on 2 DISTINCT elements of array

Tags: c, arrays, bit-manipulation

Given an array of non-negative integers, what is the fastest and most efficient way to find the maximum no. that can be obtained by performing bitwise and (i.e, & operator) on 2 DISTINCT elements of the array?

This  is my code until now :

```
max = 0
for(i=0; i<n; i++)
{
    for(j=i+1; j<n; j++)
    {
        temp = a[i] & a[j];
        if(temp > max)
            max = temp
    }
 }
```

This, of course, is the naive method. I am looking for a more efficient solution.

Maybe something like using a trie(actually a binary tree) to find max XOR of elements of array. The description for the max XOR solution can be found at http://threads-iiith.quora.com/Tutorial-on-Trie-and-example-problems?share=1

Comment: This can be a good question if you add some code and share your thoughts and attempts so far.

Comment: @barakmanos, I have used the brute-force technique so far (iterating over every pair of distinct integers in the array, compute their bitwise and, update the global maximum)...but I know that is very naive...I was wondering if there is a method to find the maximum '&' similar to the way of finding max XOR ('^') by using a trie(binary tree actually) to store the bit patterns of the array elements.

Comment: I know, I've read your earlier question with all that information (not sure why you posted it again here). In any case, you should add all these details in the body of the question, in order to make it clear.

Comment: @user2357112...consider the input array [4,2,8,10] ... here max no. that can be obtained by & of 2 DISTINCT no.s is 8 (8 & 10 = 8)  whereas 10 & 10 = 10 ... I want the code to give the answer as 8 and not as 10.

Comment: There's an O(nk) solution, where n is the number of array elements and k is the number of set bits in the result. Go over the array elements, finding the highest bit that's set in at least two array elements, then throw out everything without that bit set. Repeat, looking for the next-highest bit, until you hit the least-significant bit. I don't know whether this can be improved.

Comment: OK, now you've got my vote :)

Comment: You can look for a bitwise solution, but often that will be **slower** than the standard ternary operator if branching occurs. The ternary operator is highly optimized and will often provide better results than bit manipulation.

Comment: Exact duplicate of [Maximise the AND](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24978345/maximise-the-and). This is probably a contest question.

Comment: Just am idea. I'll try to write the code later. The idea is to create a radix tree from your array elements. The radix tree will contain a counter how many elements it contains in each subtree.  To find the max &, start from the top of the tree and descend the "1" path to a node containing at least two elements. If the "1" path can not be followed, descend by "0" path.

Comment: @RaymondChen: Nice catch. I actually thought it was the same user publishing the same question twice (see third comment from the top).

Comment: can you clarify the meaning of *distinct* in this context? E.g. if the elements are `{1, 2, 3, 4, 4}`, is `4 & 4` a permitted match?  (You didn't specify that the array contains pairwise distinct values)

Comment: @Raymond Chen ... I admit this is the question from Codechef July Cookoff, but before you start accusing me wrongly of trying to get the answer here, please let me clarify. I had already submitted my solution to the aforementioned question and had stopped doing the contest by the time the answer was given...I asked this question simply out of curiosity and had no questionable intentions. Hope you understand :)

Comment: @RaymondChen  Also I have no relation whatsoever with the other user mentioned in your comment.

Comment: "•Discussing CodeChef’s problems or any aspect of problem, on any other platform on web, on identification, could lead to disabling of respective account and banning from the community."

Answer (score 4):

I hope I have got the question right. Here's my solution to it:

You have an array of integers, say that they are unsigned integers since we are dealing with bitwise operations. Let's think of them as a string of zeroes and ones in their binary representation and then put them on top of each other.

We now have their corresponding bits aligned vertically. Let's draw vertical lines, starting from the leftmost column. If we ever encounter more than or equal to two `1`s in a column, then rule out every row that does not have the `1`s. We are to disregard the ruled out ones while drawing our further vertical lines.

You see where this is going at?

This shall go on until we have only and exactly 2 lines left that hasn't been ruled out. If we ever end up with anything else than 2, then it means something went wrong:

- Less than 2 means we had less than 2 lines initially
- More than 2 means that...

  - If there are less than what we had initially, then the ones left should all be identical
  - If there are exactly as many as we had initially, then it can be that all are the same, or every possible pair is bitwise distinct, meaning that every single pair produces `0`

Here's the code I've written that follows the logic I've described above:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <memory.h>

#define bit(_x_) (1U << (_x_))

void randomfillarray( unsigned int * arr, size_t size ) {
    srand( time( NULL ) );
    for ( int i = 0; i < size; i++ )
        arr[i] = rand( );
}

int main( ) {
    unsigned int arr[10];
    size_t size = sizeof arr / sizeof * arr;
    randomfillarray( arr, size );

    unsigned int * resultantcouple = malloc( sizeof arr );
    memcpy( resultantcouple, arr, sizeof arr );

    for ( int i = 0; i < size; i++ )
        printf( i ? " %u" : "%u", arr[i] );
    putchar( '\n' );

    int success = 0;

    for ( unsigned int thebit = bit( sizeof( int ) * 8 - 1 ); thebit; thebit >>= 1 ) {
        int count = 0;
        int * indices = NULL;
        for ( int i = 0; i < size; i++ ) {
            if ( resultantcouple[i] & thebit ) {
                indices = realloc( indices, ++count * sizeof * indices );
                indices[count - 1] = i;
            }
        }
        if ( count >= 2 ) {
            size = count;
            for ( int i = 0; i < size; i++ )
                resultantcouple[i] = resultantcouple[indices[i]];
            resultantcouple = realloc( resultantcouple, size * sizeof * resultantcouple );
        }
        if ( size == 2 ) {
            success = 1;
            break;
        }
        free( indices );
    }

    if ( success )
        printf( "Success! %u and %u are the ones.", resultantcouple[0], resultantcouple[1] );
    else
        printf( "Failure! Either all pairs are bitwise distinct, or there are less than 2 elements, or something else..." );


    putchar( '\n' );
    return 0;
}
```

Here's the same during action: http://ideone.com/hRA8tn

I'm not sure if this is the best, but it should be better than testing all out.

Comment: You may just change the `success` output to be something like `printf( "Success! %u and %u produce %u.", resultantcouple[0], resultantcouple[1], resultantcouple[0] & resultantcouple[1] );`. Also, sorry for inconsistency at `printf` with signed and unsigned integers on the first version.

Comment: "more than two 1's in a column" should be "two or more" right?

Answer (score 0):

First look at and understand the heapsort algorithm.

Turn the array into a heap which lets you access the two largest elements. This is done in linear time, O (n).

Take the two largest elements, x = largest, y = second largest. If y = 0, the solution is 0. If the highest bit in x and the highest bit in y are the same, the solution is x & y. Otherwise, clear the highest bit in x, fix the heap, and try again. The last step takes O (log n) steps, and if you are using k bit integers, like 32 or 64, it is repeated at most k times.

No extra space needed, and linear time.

Pseudo-code:

```
If n ≤ 1 there is no solution. 
Turn a [0] to a [n-1] into a heap with a [0] as the largest element. 
Repeat
    Let x = a [0].
    Let y = a [1].
    If n ≥ 3 and a [2] > a [1] then let y = a [2].
    If y = 0 then the solution is 0.
    Determine b = the highest bit of x.
    If (y & b) != 0 then the solution is x & y.
    Replace a [0] with x & (~ b)
    Turn a [0] to a [n-1] into a heap again by moving a [0] down.
```

This assumes that a [i] and a [j] are considered "distinct array elements" if i ≠ j. If you require instead that a [i] ≠ a [j] then things are slightly different. You'd have to remove duplicate entries in your array, but in case the largest elements are for example 31 and 15, you don't want to clear the highest bit in 31 and then remove it as a duplicate! So the code is more difficult.

```
Let mask = ~0. In the following, when creating a heap compare a [i] & mask, not a [i].
Turn a [0] to a [n-1] into a heap with a [0] as the largest element. 
Repeat
    If n ≤ 1 then there is no solution.
    Let x = a [0].
    Let y = a [1].
    If n ≥ 3 and a [2] & mask > y & mask then let y = a [2].

    If x = y then let n = n - 1, let a [0] = a [n], restore the heap, and continue.
    If (y & mask) = 0 then the solution is 0.
    Determine b = the highest bit of x & mask.
    If (y & b) != 0 then the solution is x & y.
    Replace mask with mask & ~b.
    Restore the heap and continue.
```

Worst case is O (n log n), for example if all elements are 1 except one that is 0.

Comment: Suppose the largest value (x) is 0x1A01, and the next (y) is 0x1010, and the next (z) is 0x1001... the x & y (0x1000) is less than x & z (0x1001), but your algorithm seems to return x & y ?? What am I missing ?

Answer (score 0):

The following worked for me for `our_n` uints in `uint our_a[our_n]`, without changing the array or copying it or anything else.  The essence is that in one pass down the array it identifies the next bit that can be added to the result so far.  Each pass only considers values which contain all the bits of the result so far:

```
  uint result ;
  uint passes ;
  uint msb ;
  uint pn ;

  at->start_clock = times(&at->start_tms) ;

  result = 0 ;
  passes = 0 ;
  msb    = (UINT_MAX >> 1) + 1 ;
  pn     = our_n ;

  do
    {
      uint seen_once ;
      uint seen_again ;

      passes += 1 ;

      seen_once  = 0 ;
      seen_again = 0 ;

      for (uint i = 0 ; i < pn ; ++i)
        {
          uint a ;

          a = our_a[i] ;

          if ((a & result) == result)
            {
              seen_again |= (a & seen_once) ;
              seen_once  |= a ;
            } ;
        } ;

      assert((seen_again & result) == result) ;

      seen_again ^= result ;

      while (msb > seen_again)
        msb >>= 1 ;

      result |= msb ;
    }
  while (msb > 1) ;
```

So, this is O(p * n), where p is the number of passes: 1..32.

If it is OK to destroy the contents of the array, then the inner loop can be changed to:

```
      k = 0 ;
      for (uint i = 0 ; i < pn ; ++i)
        {
          uint a ;

          a = our_a[i] ;

          if ((a & result) == result)
            {
              our_a[k++] = a ;

              seen_again |= (a & seen_once) ;
              seen_once  |= a ;
            } ;
        } ;
      pn = k ;
```

Of course, the first pass is now doing rather more work than it need to, so doing that separately saves a bit more.